# MongoDB Only Logging Documents In Localhost

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

[Answered] I have started using MongoDB, and it works great to an extent. When I access Compass, if I sign in as the localhost port 27017; I can see all my documents. However, I ideally want it to be logging the documents on my account in which it's not. When I sign into Compass with my account details, they are not there. In you code I am doing `MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")` and again, it logs my documents in the localhost, but not my account. I'm guessing the issue is that I am using `localhost` in connecting, if so what do I put? Or is there something I am doing wrong? I would like to save it to my account.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you're asking. Little nitpick with the code you shared, that is `MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")`. `MongoClient` is shadowed with an instance of the client connected to mongo database running on localhost

Comment: Okay, @OluwafemiSuleI will put that in. Anyway, what I am trying to say that is when I use `MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/"). MongoClient`, it only stores the documents and data on my computer. How can I get it to save on my cloud that MongoDB gives you?

Comment: @William `mongodb://localhost:27017/` will only connect to a MongoDB database running on your local machine. If you want to connect to a remote database, you need to replace `localhost:27017` with the domain or IP address and the port number where your remote database is located. For example, `mongodb://www.yourcloudservice.com:27017/`.